# Some lisp errors not showing a backtrace

Tags: debugging

I have a few custom written methods in my init file.
They run in to null issues - too often :)

Anywhen, I noticed for some errors emacs pull up a backtrace/debugger prompt for me. But often the error is shown in the minibuffer only. But its hard to troubleshoot should because there's no backtrace so the user doesn't know where to look.

Is there a toggle I'm missing to tell emacs, hey bring up a (debug) prompt when an/any error happens.

Comment: Is `debug-on-error` set to non-`nil`?

Comment: Alt-:   debug-on-error says t

Comment: Do you see the same problem if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, then bisect your init file to find the culprit. If yes, then provide a step-by-step recipe to repro the problem here, starting with `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Can you give an example? Not all errors triggers the Lisp debugger, see the `debug-ignored-errors` user option.